# A method for generating random math problems based on performance

Tags: probability-theory, statistics

I've been attempting to find out more research and resources on generating random math problems based on performance and calculated difficulty. There's a few places that I'm just now stumbling upon, but I figured I'd ask the community what they recommend reading up on.

http://www.faqs.org/patents/app/20090017427

There's an article here on an application based on research at MIT
http://www.mathscore.com/math/mathProblems.html
I'm wondering where specifically that research resides or what I can learn from it and others.

My goal is to first understand how probability, priority queues and anything else plays a role (if at all) in generating varying math problems.

Any resources and recommended reading would be most useful if you can provide that.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 3):

The only stated relation to MIT at the second link is "developed by MIT graduates". That or equivalent words appear in a few places on the web site, but I see no claim that the program or patents are related to research conducted at any university.

Wikipedia has a page on adaptive testing: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computerized_adaptive_testing

The ideas are similar to the statistical protocols used in medical trials, that allow for early stopping in case of unexpectedly good or bad results.

Comment: Ah this is precisely apart of the research I'm looking for. Thanks!